# Getting current user data with MySQL statement

Tags: plugins, php, mysql, wp-user-query

There are many widgets in Elementor which allow using MySQL statements to populate some data field. What I am trying to do is populate a field with a specific user's order data. The problem I am running into is because these Elementor MySQL editors do not allow php I have to get the current user ID, etc... with only valid MySQL syntax.

I am very new to developing in WordPress. Should I just grow a pair, move out of my plugins' basement, get a real job, and ditch Elementor or is there an easier way to configure/write these MySQL statements with php inside of them (instead of vice versa which I know is possible but these fields only allow MySQL statements)?

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ID = wp_get_current_user()->ID
```

Yes, I realize I just exposed how little I know with that statement above and how potentially dumb that was... Just let me down slowly if I am on to something, if not don't hesitate to put me in my place.

Comment: It’s impossible to get the current user without some PHP.

Comment: Which widget are you using from Elementor...? Is it a PRO widget or an Elementor add-on plugin, etc? And when you say populate, can you elaborate, are you trying to populate content on a page or data within a widget itself in the Elementor editor etc?

Comment: If the widget takes input for a MySQL statement, there will be a filter somewhere that will allow you to manipulate that statement prior to the statement being fetched and executed (I presume), so knowing the precise widget you are working with will help narrow that down for you — alternatively this could probably be achieved another way depending on where you are trying to show the data (i.e. on the rendered front end theme or within the Elementor editor itself).

Comment: @Adam, I am using the advanced data table.

Comment: If it was me... ...I'd go the "ditch Elementor" route.

Comment: @TonyDjukic you're right, can I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: I genuinely don’t want to disparage the dev team because they’ve written a lot of great code and their plug-in gives users a lot of power, but once you get to a point where you’re merging your own SQL statements into the site, there’s no sense in combatting other developers decisions to get your end result.  That’s just my approach. Sure I have to write more code, but I’m almost entirely in control of what’s happening. Just less headaches and dead ends.